# How can i add certain number after each words in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file named file.txt containing words like;

> elephant
>   donkey
>   mustang

etc...

I want new file of any name as a output as;

> elephant123
>   donkey123
>   mustang123

i just did this and stuck...

```
file = open("file.txt",'r')  
words = file.read()  
splits = words.split()  
addnums  = splits.append("123")
```

Answer (score 0):

With an input file called "INPUTFILE.txt" this will create an output file with "123" added on to the end of every entry

```
with open("INPUTFILE.txt", "r") as file:
    fileData = file.read().split("\n")

for index, item in enumerate(fileData):
    fileData[index] = item + "123"

OutputData = "\n".join(fileData)

with open("OUTPUTFILE.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(OutputData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to split the entire content. You can just iterate the file and immediately write to the outfile:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        f_out.write('{}123\n'.format(line.strip()))
```

Processing files this way can handle much larger files as the entire content never has to be stored in memory.